# Laravel Twig - Add a Macro

Tags: laravel, macros, twig

Currently, I'm switching a few of my blade templates to Twig in my Laravel project and I had a macro I was using that extended the HTML helper. This is how it appears in my directory:

```
app
   Bunny
      Controllers
      Facades
      Macros
         HTML.php
      Models
      Views
      etc...
```

In my HTML.php file, I have this:

```
HTML::macro('npc_messages', function($messages) {
    // all my logic is in here
});
```

I have a few other ones as well. I want to know how to make my Twig templates register that macro so I can just use `html_npc_messages( var );` like I can with their html_image, etc. Thank you for any assistance!

I checked out the documentation on the github URL: https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge
But I'm not fully understanding what they are doing there under the "Extensions" section.